# Why can't I map over my array with .map using rx.js

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have create a simple `Observable` pipeline.  It calls an endpoint, which returns an array of people and then I want to map over it.  Here is my code:

```
  Observable
    .fromPromise(fetch('/names').then(res => res.json()))
    .map(d => d.name)
    .subscribe(
        names => console.log("NAME", names),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    )
```

The `fetch` line returns this array

```
         [
            {
                name: 'Jason',
                age: 42
            },
            {
                name: 'Neely',
                age: 41
            },
            {
                name: 'Tristan',
                age: 21
            }
        ]
```

When I get to `.map(d => d.name)` I always get `undefined`.  It isn't iterating over the array.  The code is trying to call `.name` on the array itself.  I have tried to place another `.map` after the first one, but that doesn't fix anything.  What am I missing?  How do I fix my code?

Comment: @samsonthehero: Note that the OP is building an Observable from that promise.

Comment: Don't I want it to return a `Promise`.  I thought `fromPromise` would handle that.

Comment: The `.map` function is there, but it isn't doing what I expect it to do.

Comment: In the `map` function, I have the array.  It isn't a `Promise` or anything else.

Comment: If the `fetch` is really returning what you've said, it's not JSON, so parsing it (`res.json()`) would fail. In JSON, keys **must** be in double quotes, and strings must be in double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

First, if the `fetch` is really returning what you've said, it's not JSON, so parsing it (`res.json()`) would fail. In JSON, keys must be in double quotes, and strings must be in double quotes. But assuming it's actually valid JSON...

The `Observable` only outputs a single value, the array as a whole, not individual values for the entries in the array. Since the array has no `name` property, you get `undefined`.

Instead, either:

1. `map` the result from `res.json`, or
2. `map` the single property from the Observable

Here's #1:

```
Rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(
        fakeFetch('/names')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(a => a.map(d => d.name)) // <=====
    )
    .subscribe(
        names => console.log("NAME", names),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
```

Live Example:

```js
function fakeFetch() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100,
          {
             json: function() {
                 return JSON.parse('[' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Jason",' +
                        '"age": 42' +
                    '},' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Neely",' +
                        '"age": 41' +
                    '},' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Tristan",' +
                        '"age": 21' +
                    '}' +
                ']');
              }
            }
        );
    });
}
Rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(
        fakeFetch('/names')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(a => a.map(d => d.name))
    )
    .subscribe(
        names => console.log("NAME", names),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Here's #2, in case you want to convert from Promise to Observable early:

```
Rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(
        fakeFetch('/names')
        .then(res => res.json())
    )
    .map(a => a.map(d => d.name)) // <====
    .subscribe(
        names => console.log("NAME", names),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
```

Live Example:

```js
function fakeFetch() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100,
          {
             json: function() {
                 return JSON.parse('[' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Jason",' +
                        '"age": 42' +
                    '},' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Neely",' +
                        '"age": 41' +
                    '},' +
                    '{' +
                        '"name": "Tristan",' +
                        '"age": 21' +
                    '}' +
                ']');
              }
            }
        );
    });
}
Rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(
        fakeFetch('/names')
        .then(res => res.json())
    )
    .map(a => a.map(d => d.name)) // <====
    .subscribe(
        names => console.log("NAME", names),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Happy to see you in the `Observable` business :)

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: :-) I haven't actually used Rx.js, though I've looked at it. I read the question, and immediately wondered if Observable had a `map`, found it doesn't, and got curious about what was wrong. Then I figured it out and figured, okay, post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The promise is returning an array, so after `.fromPromise` you want to `.flatMap` to 'unwind' the array, so to speak.

```js
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
)
.flatMap(x => x)
.map(x => x.name)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```